# Remove Multiple Columns from CSV Using a Variable - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass a list of columns as a parameter to be excluded when importing a CSV file. I can get the code working when I explicitly list the columns, but want to be able pass in a parameter of the list of columns from the calling application so that I don't have to update the script each time more columns need to be excluded.

This of course works:

```
$NewCsv = Import-CSV $FileFullPath | Select * -ExcludeProperty user_id,first_name,last_name,email
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$removecolumns = "'user_id','first_name','last_name','email'"
$NewCsv = Import-CSV $AuraFileFullPath | Select * -ExcludeProperty $removecolumns
```

Nor this:

```
$removecolumns = "user_id,first_name,last_name,email"
$NewCsv = Import-CSV $AuraFileFullPath | Select * -ExcludeProperty $removecolumns
```

Or this:

```
$removecolumns = @('user_id','first_name','last_name','email')
$NewCsv = Import-CSV $AuraFileFullPath | Select * -ExcludeProperty $removecolumns
```

I'll keep digging but any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting it working using

```
 $removecolumns = @('user_id','first_name','last_name','email')
$NewCsv = Import-CSV $AuraFileFullPath | Select * -ExcludeProperty $removecolumns
```

The application that calls the script and passes in @('user_id','first_name','last_name','email') as a parameter was the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: As a [semantic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), you might remove the `@` sign and parentheses: `$removecolumns = 'user_id','first_name','last_name','email'`